# Evaluating $\iiint_v(3x^2+3y^2+3z^2) \, dv$ using Spherical Coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I'm having issues solving $\iiint_v(3x^2+3y^2+3z^2) \, dv$ using Spherical Coordinates

I made the ffg substitutions: $x=r\sin\theta\sin\phi, y=r\sin\theta \cos\phi, z=r\cos\theta$

Thus $3x^2+3y^2+3z^2=3(r^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi+r^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi+r^2\cos^2\theta)=3r^2$

Also $\dfrac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}=r^2\sin\theta$

The next step is where I'm not sure if I'm right or wrong:

$$\iiint_v3x^2+3y^2+3z^2\,dv=\iiint3r^2\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}\,dr\,d\theta \,d\phi=\iiint3r^4\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta \,d\phi$$

So was I right or wrong?

Comment: Look good to me!

Comment: spherical not polar

Comment: @coldnumber yes, $dv$ is volume.

Comment: @cardinal thanks for the correction

Comment: (1) Now that you remember it's "spherical coordinates" you should edit the title and text accordingly. (I've done the tags for you already.) (2) If you use $\theta$ as the polar angle, the usual $x$ and $y$ are $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\ y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$; your formulas have $\phi=0$ at the $y$ axis instead of the $x$ axis and oriented opposite the usual way. This is OK here due to the symmetry around the axis, and is OK even without that symmetry if you do the conversion consistently, but for some integrations you need to be aware which way $\phi$ goes.

Comment: Done @DavidK . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're using $\theta$ as the angle measured for the $z$-axis; $\phi$ as the angle on the $xy$-plane, measured from the positive $x$-axis; and $r$ as the distance from the origin.

Then the conversions from rectangular to spherical coordinates are 
$$
x=r\cos\phi\sin\theta \\
y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta \\
z=r\cos\phi
$$
(I realize this is probably what you meant to write in your question, because this is what you used when you computed $3r^2$)

---

Your conversion of the function to $3r^2$ looks good, but I think a point needs to be made about the volume element:

You're actually looking for $dV=\bigg|\dfrac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}\bigg|\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$ (the absolute value is important)

For the Jacobian, you get:

$$\bigg|\dfrac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}\bigg|=\big|\,r^2\sin\theta\big|$$

Now, in this case, since $0\leq \theta\leq \pi$, $\sin\theta$ is always nonnegative, so the Jacobian is indeed $r^2\sin\theta$, and

$$dV=r^2\sin\theta \, dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$$

---

**EDIT:** To integrate over a sphere (let's say of radius $a$) the limits will be the following:

- $r$, the distance from the origin, goes from $0$ to $a$.
- $\phi$, the angle on the $xy$-plane measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis, goes from $0$ to $2\pi$.
- $\theta$, the angle measured from the positive $z$-axis, goes from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: It appears to me that OP is using $\theta$ as the angle from the $z$-axis. I think that's where $r^2 \sin \theta$ came from.

Comment: @DavidK Ah, I see it. I'll add a disclaimer to the top of my answer.

Comment: but the jacobian is $r^2\sin\theta$ because it is used az the angle from the z-axis

Answer (score 0):

its right only,
you just need proper boundary condition of the integration to solve,
if your domain of integration is sphere then 
the all angle varies from o to 360 degree, and use the proper value of the radius to evaluate it.

Comment: What would be the boundary condition in this case? The domain of integration is the sphere. Maybe that's where I got it wrong

Comment: @ChiragPalan: Not all the angles vary from $0$ to $2\pi$, only $\theta$ does. In the derivation of spherical coordinates, $0\leq \phi\leq \pi$.

Comment: ya that true only theta varies from 0 to 360

Comment: @coldnumber please can you state the required intervals for determining the triple integral of the entire sphere?

Comment: @Obinoscopy I edited them into my answer.